# Comparing java.utilDate with LocalDate in java

Tags: java, date, localdate, date-comparison, java.util.date

I have a method wherein have to check whether a LocalDate falls in between two java.util.Date values.
there are methods after and before in java.util.Date
and there are methods isAfter and isBefore in LocalDate.

The code snippet which i have is as :

```
 /**
 * checks if date passed falls between start & end date
 *
 * @param date
 * @param startDate
 * @param endDate
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isBetween(Date date, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    return (startDate == null || date.after(startDate) || date.equals(startDate))
            && (endDate == null || date.before(endDate) || date.equals(endDate));
}
```

There is no method in the API to compare across..

Comment: Have you tried to convert `java.util.date` into LocalDate?

Comment: What do you mean *falls between*? A `Date` (despite its name) is a point int time, and at that point in time there are two or three different dates in different time zones. If the `Date` denotes 2021-11-05 at 11:00 AM in the time zone you prefer, does a `LocalDate` of 2021-11-05 then fall before and/or after?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide on many corner and edge cases. Here’s a shot.

```
public static boolean isBetween(LocalDate date, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    // Is before start?
    if (startDate != null) {
        LocalDate startLocalDate = startDate.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
        if (date.isBefore(startLocalDate)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Is after end?
    if (endDate != null) {
        LocalDate endLocalDate = endDate.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
        if (date.isAfter(endLocalDate)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // If we end up here, the date is between start and end inclusive
    return true;
}
```

I am assuming that the old-fashioned `Date` objects are to be interpreted in the default time zone of the JVM. On one hand this is standard, on the other hand the default time zone can be changed at any time, also from other programs running in the same JVM, so this is fragile. I am discarding the time of day part of the thus interpreted date. Whether the time is 00:00 or it’s 23:59:59.999, I deem the `LocalDate` inside the interval if the date agrees. You may want quite different behaviour.

If you wanted to take the time into account, you should probably convert everything to `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` instead.

As you can see, mixing old-fashioned and modern classes leads to quite some complication. I am converting `Date` to `LocalDate` in order to take advantage of java.time, which in turn also gets more complicated since the `Date`s may be `null`.

Comment: Great answer! Just a couple of points: (1) The OP has mentioned LocalDate in the description but none of the params of the method is of type, `LocalDate`. Probably, the OP wants to deal with all three params as `java.util.Date` (2) I would not do `null` check because it should be taken care of by the caller. If at all you need to do it, the solution needs a little adjustment e.g. if `if (date.isBefore(startLocalDate))` is `false` and `endDate == null`, currently `true` will be returned; not sure if it is the desired behavior.

Comment: For a solution without null checks the answer by Sikorski is probably better than mine since it’s a lot terser, and I find it clear to read.

Answer (score 0):

Convert LocalDate to String and convert this String to java.util.Date and you can use your method.

To convert LocalDate to String:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();                                    
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");          
String localDateToString = localDate.format(dateFormatter1);
```

And to convert String to Date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date1=formatter1.parse(sDate1);
```

Once you've converted LocalDate to Date, you can compare dates using your method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert java.util.Date to LocalDate instances for comparison. Since you have to compare LocalDate with other dates, so losing the time part seems to be a logical compromise here.

```
public static boolean isBetween(LocalDate localDate, Date start, Date end){
    LocalDate startLocalDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(start.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate endLocalDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(end.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    return (localDate.isEqual(startLocalDate) || localDate.isEqual(endLocalDate)) || (localDate.isAfter(startLocalDate) && localDate.isBefore(endLocalDate));
}
```

I have made the endDate as inclusive upper limit.

Comment: No bad suggestion. The code in the question seems to indicate that start and end may be `null`. Converting `start` to an `Instant` goes a bit simpler: `start.toInstant()` (same for `end`).